# How can I create a custom help menu in Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

When I run `fab --list` I get output as

```
error                        Call ``func`` with given error ``message``.
get_all_tags
get_head_position
get_latest_patch
get_latest_tag
get_pending_patches
glob                         Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.
handle_prompt_abort
help
indent                       Return ``text`` indented by the given number of spaces.
```

this contains several user defined functions like `get_all_tags` `get_head_position` etc but without any description.
I wish to include the description for these functions as well so that my list looks something like this

```
error                        Call ``func`` with given error ``message``.
get_all_tags                 Returns a list of all available tags
get_head_position            Returns the current Head position
get_latest_patch             Returns most recently created patch file name
get_latest_tag               Returns the most recent tags among all the tags
get_pending_patches          Returns list of all patches which are yet to be applied
glob                         Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.
handle_prompt_abort
help
indent                       Return ``text`` indented by the given number of spaces.
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add docstring to the functions.

```
@task
def get_all_tags():
    "This is a docstring ..."
```

The docstring is used to display help message.

According to [`fab -l` option documentation](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/stable/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-l):

> Imports a fabfile as normal, but then prints a list of all discovered
>   tasks and exits. **Will also print the first line of each task’s
>   docstring, if it has one, next to it (truncating if necessary.)**